# Convert HTML to Django template

Tags: python, html

I want to create a python script that would change html documents, I'm kind of lost and don't know where to start, I've tried a couple of things that didn't work at all and don't think its worth posting them here.

The problem is that with Django, it is better to write links like this:

```
    <link href="{% static 'assets/css/cssfile.css' %}"/>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jsfile.js' %}"></script>
    <img src="{% static 'assets/images/desktop.png' %}"/>
```

But I have a template, actually several templates, with lots of static assets that are referenced in the normal way, like this:

```
<link href="assets/css/cssfile.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="assets/js/jsfile.js"></script>
<img src="assets/images/desktop.png"/>
```

So, I've been trying to create a script that looks for "assets" and the edits the line, replacing `href="assets` with `href="{% static'`... and then adds `' %}` at the end. I think this would be a very valuable script for django developers that work with templates, maybe it is already out there somewhere.

Is there any automated way to convert the normal href/src attributes to use Django tags?

Comment: I think the title of your question is very unclear: "Python. Change an html file." Can you improve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you looking for help writing the script, or looking to see if such a thing exists already, or..?

Comment: Get an editor with regular expression support. On vim it is something like `<ESC>:%s/\(src|href)="\(assets\/.+?\)/\1="{% static '\2' %}"/g<ENTER>`

Comment: @PauloScardine you should elaborate this into an answer, this is really the point here.

Comment: ENOQUERY - Not a question.

Comment: @Robᵩ How could it not be a question? I explain a problem and then the Obvious underlying question is "How can I do that correctly?". :/

Comment: There is no question in your post. There are several declaritive statements that express your knowledge, your desire, and your speculation, but there is no question. Implicit questions are generally only obvious to the asker; in this case it is clear that each respondent inferred a different question. For Stack Overflow, explicit questions will generate higher-quality answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you know regular expressions. My prefered way to make this kind change is using an editor with regular expression support, then it is a matter of search & replace. If you are using Django, pycharm from jetbrains is well worth the money. I like vim.

Each editor has some variation on how regex capture groups work (please, check your editor/ide docs), but the general format of such a regular expression is:

```
(src|href)="(assets\/.+?)"
```

It is searching for a `src` or `href` attribute starting with `assets`, capturing everything between the quotes. So, capture group 1 is the attribute and capture group 2 is the value - the replace expression is:

```
\1="{% static '\2' %}"
```

On some editors you must use `$1` and `$2` instead of `\1` and `\2`. In vim you must escape the parens IICR. Also, some editors do not support this syntax (`.+?`) for non-greedy "capture everything", you may have to use `[^"]+` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not good at regular expressions. Anyway, I will try it and let you know how it went. I use Sublime Text 3 btw.

Comment: This will work ipsis literis on st3 search/replace box if you enable regular expressions (the small `[.*]` button on the left side).

Answer (score 4):

There exists a python package which does that for you, please refer to : https://pypi.org/project/djangify/

Answer (score 0):

This is the command for vi editor. Run this in escape mode.

:%s/href="([^ ]+)"/href="{% static \1 %}"/g